# The boundedness of $L_1$ norm $\|(I+A)^{-1}\|_1$ if both $\|A\|_1$ and $\|A^{-1}\|_1$ are bounded

Tags: linear-algebra

> Assume that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ is a positive semi-definite matrix, both  $\|A\|_1$ and $\|A^{-1}\|_1$ are uniformly bounded as $N \to \infty.$ Here $\| \cdot \|_1$ is the induced $L_1$ Norm.
> Prove that there exists a constant $\kappa > 0$ such that
> $$\|(I_N+A)^{-1}\|_1 \leq \kappa $$ as $N \to \infty.$
> Else show a counterexample.

I attempted to demonstrate that the boundedness of $\|(I_N+A)^{-1}\|_1$ can be proven using the definition of $\| \cdot \|_1$ as follows

$$ \|(I_N + A)^{-1} \|_1 = \sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{ \|(I_N + A)^{-1} x\|_1 }{\|x\|_1} = \sup_{z \neq 0} \frac{ \|z\|_1 }{\|(I_N+A)z\|_1} \leq \sup_{z \neq 0} \frac{ \|z\|_1 }{|\|Az\|_1 - \|z\|_1|} = \sup_{z \neq 0} \frac{1}{ \Big| \frac{\|Az\|_1}{\|z\|_1} - 1 \Big| } $$

However, it seems possible that $\inf_{z} \Big|\frac{\|Az\|_1}{\|z\|_1} - 1 \Big|=0$, so I doubt this proof is wrong.

But intuitively, $(I_N + A)^{-1}$ seems to be smaller than $A^{-1}$, and when we consider $L_2$ norm, it is easy to find that $\|(I_N + A)^{-1}\|_2 \leq 1$, so I guess the boundedness still holds when we consider $L_1$ norm.

Any guidance on how to tackle this problem? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Can you do this in case $A$ is diagonal?  Can the spectral theorem reduce the general case to the diagonal case?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: The diagonal case is trivial ($\|(1+D)^{-1}\|_1\le 1$ when $D_{jj}\ge 0$), but the unitary matrix that diagonalizes $A$ could have large $1$ norm.

Comment: Yes, for example, consider a unitary matrix where the first row is $N^{-1/2}(1,1,...,1)$. So it seems that the eigenvalue decomposition theorem cannot be utilized either.

Answer (score 1):

Take $A=-I$. Then both $\Vert A\Vert_1,\Vert A^{-1}\Vert_1 $ are bounded although $I+A=0$ is not invertible.

Comment: Thanks, but I assume that $A$ is a positive semi-definite matrix so it cannot be $-I$